# AWS Athena - How to Parameterize the SQL query

Tags: amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

I want to provide runtime values to the query in  Select & Create table statements. What are the ways to parameterize Athena SQL queries?
I tried with `PREPARE` & `EXECUTE` statements from Presto however it is not working in  Athena console. Do we need any external scripts like Python to call it?

```
PREPARE my_select1
FROM SELECT * from NATION;

EXECUTE my_select1 USING 1;
```

Answer (score 5):

The [SQL and HiveQL Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/language-reference.html) documentation does not list `PREPARE` nor `EXECUTE` as available commands.

You would need to fully construct your `SELECT` statement before sending it to Amazon Athena.

Comment: Thanks .which means currently  there is no way to parameterize SQL queries (DDL ,select statements) in AWS Athena?

Comment: Correct.  PreparedStatement not yet available in the Athena JDBC driver.  Many have asked for this, being tracked here: https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/1195

Answer (score 3):

You have to upgrade to Athena engine version 2 and now this seems to be supported as of 2021-03-12 but I can't find an official report:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-with-prepared-statements.html

Comment: It has just been announced https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/07/amazon-athena-adds-parameterized-queries-to-improve-reusability-and-security/

Answer (score 1):

Athena does not support [Parameterized](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/other-notable-limitations.html) queries. How ever you can create user-defined functions that you can call in the body of a query. Refer to this to know more about [UDFs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-udf.html).

Comment: this answer got my hopes up but no, Athena does not support table-valued UDFs (that you might use to parameterize a query) - the linked documentation here is about scalar udfs